# Why does the approach of row-reducing an augmented matrix work in finding the matrix of a linear map relative to two bases?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say you're given a linear map on $\mathbb{C}$: $T(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,0)$ and let's say you want to find the matrix $\mathcal{M}$ of $T$ relative to the standard basis and the basis $\{(1,i),(-i,2)\}$, why does the method below of row-reducing the augmented matrix work in finding the that matrix $\mathcal{M}$?

$$\left[\matrix{1 & -i \\ i &2 }\right|\left.\matrix{1 & 0 \\ 0&0}\right]\xrightarrow[]{\qquad\quad\qquad}\underset{}{\left[\matrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 &1 }\right|\left.\matrix{2 & 0 \\ -i&0}\right]}$$

Comment: Think about what the process of row-reduction is in terms of matrix multiplication.

Comment: @amd I know that it's multiplication of elementary matrices, but I don't what it is when we're row reducing an augmented matrix with more than 1 column

Comment: Well, how does matrix multiplication work? In particular, examine the product column-by-column.

Comment: @amd i think i got it, we can write the augmented matrix there as $AX=B$, our final job shows that $X=A^{-1}B$ isn't it? if so, please write a short answer and i will accept it to reward you for your efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row-reduction is equivalent to left-multiplying by some invertible square matrix $E$. If the matrix is augmented, then by the rules of matrix multiplication, the right-hand side of the augmented matrix is also left-multiplied by $E$. If the left-hand side is invertible, then its RREF is $I$, so $E=A^{-1}$ and row reduction changes $\left[A\mid B\right]$ into $\left[I\mid A^{-1}B\right]$.

Let’s denote the standard basis by $\mathcal E$ and the other ordered basis in your question by $\mathcal B$. The matrix with the elements of $\mathcal B$ for its columns is then the change-of-basis matrix $[\operatorname{id}]_{\mathcal E}^{\mathcal B}$ from $\mathcal B$ to $\mathcal E$. Per the above, if we augment this matrix with $[T]_{\mathcal E}^{\mathcal E}$ and row reduce, we end up with $$\left([\operatorname{id}]_{\mathcal E}^{\mathcal B}\right)^{-1} [T]_{\mathcal E}^{\mathcal E} = [\operatorname{id}]_{\mathcal B}^{\mathcal E} [T]_{\mathcal E}^{\mathcal E} = [T]_{\mathcal B}^{\mathcal E},$$ i.e., the matrix of $T$ relative to the standard basis (input) and $\mathcal B$ (output), as required.

Note that to obtain $[T]_{\mathcal B}^{\mathcal B}$ you’ll need to change the input basis as well, i.e., right-multiply by the appropriate change-of-basis matrix.